# How to convert integer/string value to floating value from my excel in java poi?

Tags: java

How to convert integer/string value to floating value from my excel in java poi? Say for example, I have, 1.23456 in a cell and I want to print it intact.

Comment: use Float.valueOf(); still better explains the problem

Comment: with the help of `createRichTextString` you can create 

    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper.createRichTextString(properties.getProperty("CELL_No"))